# How to fix putting matching brackets in Mathematica after adding new keyboard layout on Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: ubuntu, wolfram-mathematica

I added the Turkish keyboard layout on a laptop with US keyboard on Kubuntu 19.04. Now putting matching square brackets by pressing Alt + ] on Mathematica when I switch back to the US layout is gone (the regular parentheses and the curly brackets are still fine).

I have searched on Google as to the modification of the init.m file so as to be able to produce the shortcut again. It failed.

Update 1: When I switch to the US layout, the problem persists.

Update 2: When I remove the second layout and turn off "Configure layouts" under Keyboard > Layouts and afterwards re-install Mathematica, things go back to normal.

Comment: What does the menu Insert / Typesetting / Matching [] show as the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Interestingly, it is still shown to be Alt + ].